# Making Android Toolbar

Tags: android

I downloaded Google's Navigation Drawer sample app and the app uses `android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle`. v4 was deprecated and I tried using `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle`, but `ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close )` reports error at R.drawable.ic_drawer saying that it should be a Toolbar object. Can anyone here explain or point to some Toolbar creation tutorial, since Google doesn't have any of their own?

Comment: Just omit that argument. There's a second constructor like this: `ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity, DrawerLayout, int, int)`.

Comment: Wow, that Works. Ty very much. Post this as an answer if you want so I can mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The v7 version of `ActionBarDrawerToggle` has two constructors; one that takes a `Toolbar`, and one that does not. In your case, you can simply omit the third argument in your posted constructor call, and the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` will find what it needs itself.

Additionally, if you're following an old example, you might also receive a deprecation warning for the `DrawerLayout#setDrawerListener()` method. With the newest version, you should now use the `addDrawerListener()` method.

And lastly, you might want to update the example to use `AppCompatActivity` as well. I'm pretty sure the v7 version of `ActionBarDrawerToggle` works just fine with a regular `Activity` and `ActionBar`, but if something doesn't seem right, it might be the version difference.